# How to select one record at a time without using cursor?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have two tables in SQL SERVER.

DBO.VitalPatientDetails=>

| PatientDetailsId | PatientId | PatientName | UnitName | BedName | PatientDOB | LastAlarmReceivedAt |

DBO.VitalAlarmDetails=>

| Id | PatientDetailsId (Refers VitalPatientDetails.PatientDetailsId) | VitalGenerationTime | FileName |

I need to retrive all fields of DBO.VitalAlarmDetails grouped by PatientDetailsId ordered by VitalGenerationTime in ascending order.
I have written cursor for this as below and it is returning multiple result sets. I need to get it in single set without using cursor. I just want to know whether I can do this without cursor.

```
DECLARE @PatientDetailsId BIGINT
DECLARE @getAlarmDetails CURSOR

SET @getAlarmDetails = CURSOR FOR SELECT PatientDetailsId FROM VitalPatientDetails

OPEN @getAlarmDetails
    FETCH NEXT FROM @getAlarmDetails INTO @PatientDetailsId

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM VitalAlarmDetails
        WHERE PatientDetailsId = @PatientDetailsId
        ORDER BY VitalGenerationTime ASC

        FETCH NEXT FROM @getAlarmDetails INTO @PatientDetailsId
    END
CLOSE @getAlarmDetails
DEALLOCATE @getAlarmDetails
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need a sinle VitalGenerationTime (say MIN VitalGenerationTime) per PatientDetailsId?

Comment: Can you please post your current query using cursors and any sample data and the desired output.

Comment: I need to retrieve all fields of table DBO.VitalAlarmDetails as it is.

Comment: And what do you mean by GROUPED BY PatientDetailsId? Ordered by? different result sets?

Comment: I need to get alarm details of one patient one after other order by its generation time. Then same for next patient after first patient in same result.

Comment: So this is returning **multiple** result sets? Is that what you are looking for? What is your intensions with this?

Comment: I need to get all result in single set without using cursor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a `WHILE` loop to replace the `CURSOR`. I posted an example in another SO question:

[SQL Server stored procedure avoid cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077162/sql-server-stored-procedure-avoid-cursor/11077218#11077218)

It'd become something like the following:

```
SELECT @PatientDetailsId = MIN (PatientDetailsId) FROM VitalAlarmDetails 
WHILE @PatientDetailsId IS NOT NULL
BEGIN

   ' Do stuff here

   SELECT @PatientDetailsId = MIN (PatientDetailsId ) FROM VitalAlarmDetails WHERE PatientDetailsId > @PatientDetailsId 

END
```

Edit:

To return a set instead of going at it row by row, use something like this:

```
SELECT 
    VAD.*
FROM 
VitalAlarmDetails VAD JOIN
        VitalPatientDetails VPD ON VAD.PatientDetailsId  = VPD.PatientDetailsId
```

Edit2:

The `JOIN` still did not yield the expected results. Suggested to use a temp table inside the `WHILE` loop to store results. This seems to have worked.

Comment: I am getting multiple result sets with this.

Comment: What do you mean multiple result sets? Are you seeing the same PatientDetailsID more than once?

Comment: I am not seeing same PatientDetailsID more than once. For each PatientDetailsID result set is different as it is selecting for each patient id through while loop. Now I am trying with UNION so that all comes in only one result set.

Comment: It will not return me result in single set.
For example:
SELECT PatientName FROM DBO.VitalPatientDetails WHERE PatientDetailsId=1 
SELECT PatientName FROM DBO.VitalPatientDetails WHERE PatientDetailsId=2 
By executing these two statements will give me two different result sets.

SELECT PatientName FROM DBO.VitalPatientDetails WHERE PatientDetailsId=1 
UNION
SELECT PatientName FROM DBO.VitalPatientDetails WHERE PatientDetailsId=2
By executing above statements will give me single result set.

Comment: @Ajinkya - Not following. The query with the JOIN should return a single resultset as well. Can you show an example of what it returns in your case?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18911/discussion-between-ajinkya-and-schmitzit)

Answer (score 0):

OK, so if I understand you correctly **a single result set, ordered by VitalGenerationTime (and from using the cursor ordered by PatientDetailsId?**

How about something like

```
SELECT  PatientDetailsId,
        VitalGenerationTime
FROM    VitalAlarmDetails
ORDER BY    PatientDetailsId,
            VitalGenerationTime
```

Comment: I want all fields of table VitalAlarmDetails.