# GENERIC STORED PROCEDURE TO AUDIT TABLE UPDATE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, triggers

Is there a generic stored procedure to audit the table. I have actually made one but I don't think its efficient and the stored procedure is quite long. If someone knows a better way to do it then please help me out...!

This is my table trigger.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger3]
ON  [dbo].[UserInfo]
AFTER Update
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @TABLENAME VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @var varbinary

    SELECT * INTO #TEMPINSERTED FROM inserted
    SELECT * INTO #TEMPDELETED FROM deleted 

    SET @var = COLUMNS_UPDATED()

    EXEC TetsProc #TEMPINSERTED, #TEMPDELETED, @@PROCID, @var

    DROP TABLE #TEMPINSERTED 
    DROP TABLE #TEMPDELETED  
END
```

This is my stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TetsProc]
( @insertTable varchar(max),
@deleteTable  varchar(max),
@IDZ varchar(max),
@var1 varbinary 
)
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @TABLE AS TABLE (COL_NAME NVARCHAR(MAX))
DECLARE @idTable INT

SELECT  @idTable = T.id 
FROM    sysobjects P JOIN sysobjects T ON P.parent_obj = T.id 
WHERE   P.id = @IDZ

declare @q1  nvarchar(max),@q2 nvarchar(max) 
set @q1 = 'select * from ' + @insertTable
set @q2 =  'select * from ' +  @deleteTable


DECLARE @TABLENAME NVARCHAR(250)


SELECT @TABLENAME = OBJECT_NAME(parent_obj)
FROM sysobjects WHERE ID = @IDZ

 ----RETURN COLUMNS IF THEY ARE UPDATED----   
 SELECT  @idTable = T.id 
 FROM    sysobjects P JOIN sysobjects T ON P.parent_obj = T.id 
 WHERE   P.id = @@procid

DECLARE @Columns_UpdateD VARCHAR(50)

SELECT  @Columns_Update = ISNULL(@Columns_Updated + ', ', '') + name 
FROM    syscolumns 
WHERE   id = @idTable   
AND  CONVERT(VARBINARY,REVERSE(@var1)) & POWER(CONVERT(BIGINT, 2), colorder - 1)  > 0

select status into #TmpcolumnsUpdated from dbo.ParseByComma(@Columns_UpdateD)


DECLARE @QRY1 NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @QRY2 NVARCHAR(MAX)
declare @column_name varchar(50)

DECLARE cursorColumnName CURSOR FOR  
select status from #TmpcolumnsUpdated
OPEN cursorColumnName   
FETCH NEXT FROM cursorColumnName INTO @column_name 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
   SET @QRY1= 'SELECT '+@column_name + '  FROM '+ @insertTable 
   SET @QRY2= 'SELECT '+@column_name + '  FROM ' + @deleteTable


DECLARE @tab AS TABLE (OLD_COL VARCHAR(10)) 
DECLARE @tab1 AS TABLE (NEW_COL VARCHAR(10)) 


INSERT into @tab EXECUTE  sp_executesql @QRY2
INSERT into @tab1 EXECUTE  sp_executesql @QRY1



DECLARE @OLD_VALUE VARCHAR(MAX)=(SELECT OLD_COL FROM @tab)
DECLARE @NEW_VALUE VARCHAR(MAX)=(SELECT NEW_COL FROM @tab1)

IF(@OLD_VALUE!=@NEW_VALUE)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO UpdateInfo (Table_Name,Col_Name,Old_Value,New_Value,Time)
  (
   SELECT
   @TABLENAME,
   @column_name,
   @OLD_VALUE,
   @NEW_VALUE,
   GETDATE()
  )
  SELECT * FROM UpdateInfo 
  END

DELETE FROM @tab
DELETE FROM @tab1


FETCH NEXT FROM cursorColumnName INTO @column_name
END   

CLOSE cursorColumnName   
DEALLOCATE cursorColumnName

drop table #TmpcolumnsUpdated

END
```

Comment: Please don't shout at us

Comment: Please don't use capitals everywhere - it's considered to be SHOUTING!

Comment: oh m sorry, i had no intention of shouting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a sure way to drag down the performance of your server.

If you are using SQL Server 2012, I'd recommend you to check out [Sql Server Audit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280386.aspx) instead.

If you have to stick with your mechanism, at the very least lose the cursor in the PROC.

Comment: Thanks for the link. But the use of cursor is required according to my mechanism. M actually new to sql and i dint even know about cursor, i learnt it just to implement in my above proc as it was required. If there is any other alternative to cursor which i can implement in my proc to achieve the same result then please let me know. Thanks :)

Comment: @ik024 - See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077162/sql-server-stored-procedure-avoid-cursor/11077218#11077218

Basically instead of a cusror, you use a WHILE loop. Much less resource intensive. 

You're aware that your logging mechanism would have an enormous impact on the server, right? You're absolutely right that it's not efficient.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with logging table changes in a trigger. (Although I wouldn't do it like above!) It all depends on what your trying to do. For example looking at that Sql Server Audit, it would appear that is fine when you want to check for modifications rarely as it writes to a flat file, so data retrieval will be slow.